# Scale the gamma distribution

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution

I have a question regarding the distribution of a random variable $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{k}$ given that we know that $\frac{1}{\theta} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{k} \text { has the Gamma }(n, 1) \text { distribution. }$

I know that the gamma distribution has the scaling property so the first parameter should be $\mathrm {Gamma'}(n/\theta, ?)$ where $\mathrm {Gamma}'$ denotes our desired distribution, yet I don't know how to find the second parameter. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The first parameter doesn't change: it's the shape parameter.  What you do with the second parameter depends on whether it's a scale or rate (inverse scale)--but that description contains the answer to your question, because $\theta$ scales the Gamma distribution up to the sum of the $X_i^k.$

Comment: @whuber According to this, the first paramter does change. right?http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GammaS.pdf

Comment: You need to pay attention to the conventions: your reference swaps the parameters.

Comment: @whuber , so, to see if its clear to me, then $\sum X_i$ should be $Gamma′(nθ,1)$  and thus have mean nθ and expectation nθ^2? This is confusing to me..Thank you

Comment: A basic property of scaling is that when you multiply any number by $\theta$ -- which is what you must do to obtain $\sum X_i^k$ from a Gamma variate -- its square is multiplied by $\theta^2.$  Thus, when you multiply a random variable by $\theta$ its expectation must be multiplied by $\theta$ and its variance by $\theta^2.$

Answer (score 1):

First, since there are different parametrizations in use for the Gamma distribution you should always specify which you are using. It seems to be the shape-scale parametrization, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Second, you are complicating the Q with an irrelevant sum. Stary with defining
$$ Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{k}$$
Then your question looks simpler: What is the distribution of $Y$ given that
$$ Y/\theta \sim \mathcal{Gamma}(n, 1) $$
where $n$ is the shape parameter and the scale is 1. Division will not change the shape. How does the scale change? Multiplication (or division) of a random variable with a constant simply changes the scale the same way, so the scale of $Y$ must be $\theta$. Therefore,
$$ Y \sim \mathcal{Gamma}(n, \theta) $$